# Return data from PHP to JavaScript using AJAX - data type error?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am using AJAX to return a query to my JavaScript function, but I am having an issue returning the json_encode. I might have an error in the data type somewhere, but thought to check here for some advice.

This is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'testajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {value},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);}
});
```

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
require 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pword, $database, 3306);
$insertquery = $connection->prepare("SELECT tracking_type, tracking_change_date, vessel_fcm_new, vessel_hull_id_new, vessel_name_new, vessel_length_new, vessel_manufacturer_new, vessel_manufacturer_id_new, vessel_year_new, vessel_value_new, owner_id_new, loss_payee_id_new, policy_id_new, policy_start_date_new, policy_end_date_new FROM tracking WHERE tracking_type = ?");
$insertquery->bind_param("i", $trackingtype);
//$trackingtype = $_POST['value'];
$trackingtype = 1;
$insertquery->execute();
$insertquery->bind_result($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_value_new, $owner_id_new, $loss_payee_id_new, $policy_id_new, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_end_date_new);
while ($insertquery->fetch()){
    $data = array($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_value_new, $owner_id_new, $loss_payee_id_new, $policy_id_new, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_end_date_new);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

If I only have 1 row matching this query, then it works fine. But as soon as I add another row that matches the select query, it does not return properly to the JavaScript function, but does display fine in the browser (if you visit testajax.php).

This is currently how the data is being returned. Maybe I have an error in the data type being usesd:

```
["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693",null,"Makers Mark","22","sdgfsg3","256632asdasd",2014,263,"217","11",null,null,null]["Insert","2018-05-27","fFH465","FDDEE453","GIIGE","22","Shippers","2432465we",2014,205222,"Smith Jones","Capital One",null,null,null]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit might have given you a clue *If I only have 1 row matching this query, then it works fine*

So save your rows in an array and then send the whole array like this

```
while ($insertquery->fetch()){
    $data[] = array($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, 
                $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_length_new, 
                $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, 
                $vessel_year_new, $vessel_value_new, $owner_id_new,     
                $loss_payee_id_new, $policy_id_new, $policy_start_date_new, 
                $policy_end_date_new);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

EDIT:

A simple test of this code would be

```
$data[] = array('Insert','2018-05-26', 1);
$data[] = array('Insert','2018-05-26', 2);

echo json_encode($data);
```

This will generate

```
[
 ["Insert","2018-05-26",1],
 ["Insert","2018-05-26",2]
]
```

and not the sample output you suggest.

Comment: this is something I tried before, so the return data looks like this now: [["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693",null,"Makers Mark","22","sdgfsg3","256632asdasd",2014,263,"217","11",null,null,null]][["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693",null,"Makers Mark","22","sdgfsg3","256632asdasd",2014,263,"217","11",null,null,null],["Insert","2018-05-27","fFH465","FDDEE453","GIIGE","22","Shippers","2432465we",2014,205222,"Smith Jones","Capital One",null,null,null]] However, console.log(data[0]); or data[1] does not work

Comment: I dont see how this code would genarate that JSON String

Comment: Then you are not doing exactly what I suggested. See my edit

Comment: i'm beating myself up now....I forgot to move the encode outside of the loop ;) --- I think that was my issue the whole time lol.. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No sweat, we have all been there

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is return an array of objects. Not multiple objects.

```
$to_return = [];
while ($insertquery->fetch()){
    $data = array($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, $vessel_fcm_new, $vessel_hull_id_new, $vessel_name_new, $vessel_length_new, $vessel_manufacturer_new, $vessel_manufacturer_id_new, $vessel_year_new, $vessel_value_new, $owner_id_new, $loss_payee_id_new, $policy_id_new, $policy_start_date_new, $policy_end_date_new);
    $to_return[] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($to_return);
```

Comment: this is something I tried before, so the return data looks like this now: 

[["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693",null,"Makers Mark","22","sdgfsg3","256632asdasd",2014,263,"217","11",null,null,null]][["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693",null,"Makers Mark","22","sdgfsg3","256632asdasd",2014,263,"217","11",null,null,null],["Insert","2018-05-27","fFH465","FDDEE453","GIIGE","22","Shippers","2432465we",2014,205222,"Smith Jones","Capital One",null,null,null]]

However, console.log(data[0]); or data[1] does not work

Comment: @dataviews Updated my answer

Comment: ___don't forget to parse it to JSON___ Not necessary when using `dataType:'json',`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing an array of columns for each pass through the loop and therefore the JSON is not be correctly encoded as an array of arrays; you can modify your code as follows:

```
$results = array();
while ($insertquery->fetch()) {
  $newResult = array($tracking_type, $tracking_change_date, ...);
  array_push($results, $newResult);
}
$encoded = json_encode($results);
echo $encoded;
```

Will print something like this:

```
[
    ["Insert","2018-05-26","JBL5693", ...],
    ["Insert","2018-05-27","JBL5694", ...],
    ...
]
```

Note that it's better to design a client<>server interface to use an array of objects, something like:

```
[
    {"tracking_type": "Insert", "tracking_change_date": "2018-05-26", "vessel_fcm_new": "JBL5693", ...},
    {"tracking_type": "Insert", "tracking_change_date": "2018-05-26", "vessel_fcm_new": "JBL5693", ...},
    ...
]
```

This approach has the advantage that the client client does not need to know the order of the columns, rather it can directly access the properties it cares about.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to keep

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

outside of the while loop.